# What is $C_a^b$ and $H_a^b$?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

What is $C_0^1$ and $C_0^2$? What is $C_a^b$ I suppose is what I want to know. It seems when $a=0$, i.e. $C_0^b(\Omega)$ we have the set of all functions such that they are $b$ continuous and are $0$ on the boundary. Is that correct?

I.e. $C_0^b(\Omega) = \{ f\in C^b(\Omega) : f|_{\partial \Omega}=0\}$?

Furthermore then is $C_a^b = \{ f\in C^b(\Omega): f|_{\partial \Omega} =a\}$?

---

What is $H_0^1$? Seems to be the completion of $C_0^1$?

Comment: You're trying to prove that there's a unique solution $u \in H^1_0(\Omega)$ such that [...], but you don't even know what $H^1_0(\Omega)$?! Take a step back, why are you trying to prove this? Is this an assignment you were given? In what context were you given this assignment, a class? Did you go to the lectures? Doesn't the class have a syllabus with a list of books you could read? Aren't there lecture notes somewhere?

Comment: I'm trying to help you find the answer to this sort of question on your own... If you're given some exercise and there's a notation you're not familiar with, there are probably ways for you to find out what it is.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi The class notes are not clear, and the book list doesn't have anything that covers these at all(I checked at the library in Kreysszzig[or similar] and in Yuli edilmanm[or similar]) Went to the lectures yes, they left me we the questions above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$C^k$ is the space of $k$ times continuously differentiable functions. $H^k$ is the Sobolev space consisting of $k$ times weakly differentiable functions with all weak derivatives in $L^2$. A subscript of $0$ in either case can denote different things: in a bounded domain it indicates zero boundary conditions. In an unbounded domain, some authors use it to mean that the limit at infinity is zero, while others use it to mean that the functions in question have compact support. (Usually, I see the former usage, with a subscript of $c$ used to indicate the latter.)

There are two common definitions of "zero boundary conditions" in a Sobolev space. One is that the trace of the functions is zero, where the trace is the "weak version" of the "restriction to the boundary" operator. (More precisely, it is the extension of the restriction to the boundary operator from the continuous functions to the Sobolev functions.) The other is to define $H^k_0$ as the closure of $C^k_0$ in the $H^k$ norm. These definitions are equivalent (though this requires proof!)

Comment: Thanks very much, your comments in the first paragraph are especially helpful since I believe I found the latter on wikipedia which caused much of my confusion.

In regard to the second paragraph, I'll try to glean it out of my notes.